# brakes still pulsating

Tags: brakes

replaced rotors and pads(rotors twice)and still pulsating. Are the calipers the only thing left that could cause the pulsating? I checked the slides on the calipers the were ok( not stuck or frozen). I also removed the ABS fuse to see if that was causing the problem and that was not the problem. On two occasions on very cold days in the winter 0 to 5 degrees the brakes did not work the first time using them but were unstuck by pumping them once or twice seeming like they were freezing up. The pulsating problem started after this had happened not sure if this is connected. I bought the car in Oct. 2014 brakes were fine then noticed pulsating started when applying brakes heavy braking for exit off hwy. Pulsating just got worse as time went on now they pulsate going 20 mph under normal braking. Please help

Comment: Instead of asking another question for the same problem, please update your older question. Putting out another question is not going to help you solve your issue.

Comment: sorry, kinda green at this no ill intent